# Trying to understand variable scope in python

Tags: python

I gave this following program in Python just to understand scopes of variables, but I'm getting the error:

```
count = 0
def hello_func():
    if(count == 5):
        return 0
    print("Hello")
    count+=1
    hello_func()

hello_func()
```

Error :

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong? And how do I declare count has global variable without altering the structure of the above program?

Answer (score 0):

When using global variables within a function, you need to declare it explicitly:

```
count = 0
def hello_func():
    global count
    if(count == 5):
        return 0
    print("Hello")
    count+=1
    hello_func()

hello_func()
```

The `global count` in the third line declares I am using the global variable.